# Typescript type safe string with dot notation for query nested object

Tags: typescript, types, nested, typescript-typings, keyof

I am working with Typescript and firebase and I have a small abstraction layer with this function to search for a unique document base on its field name and its value.

```
  where<K extends keyof (T & DocumentEntity)>(fieldName: K, operator: WhereFilterOp, value: unknown): Query<T> {
    this.addCriterion(new WhereCriterion(fieldName as string, operator, value));
    return this;
  }
```

This works well when I want to query with a field at the base of the document, for example:

Model:

```
order: Order = {
  orderId: baseId
  item: { ... }
  price: { ... }
  restaurant: {
    restaurantId: nestedId
    name: chezGaston
  }
}
```

Query:

```
    const order = await this.documentPersistence.findUnique(
      new Query<order>().where('orderId', '==', incomingOrderId)
    );
```

But now I want to query base on the id of a nested object.

```
const order = await this.documentPersistence.findUnique(
      new Query<order>()
        .where('restaurant.restaurantId', '==', integration),
    );
```

And this gives me a static error `TS2345: Argument of type '"restaurant.restaurantId"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Order'.`

**How can I fix my function so it accepts Nested object as keyof my object?**

I don't want to use `// @ts-ignore`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this as of TypeScript 4.1.

Click the playground example to see it in action:

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgSQLZgDYB4AqAaKAaSggA9gIA7AEwGcoBrCEAewDMocA%20KAXgCgoREuSp0otYACcAlpQDmgqAH5OAbUIBdERRr0AShADGLKdSyTZCgnEoguSoapwbtZXeICCUqXBAAZGSYsW3tHIRVhAB8oAAMAEgBvQgBfADok%20CQ0TFxXAgBRUiMMAFdqCCwmVg4XLQJq9ihQtU0uLhTY8KEALmi4pNSMxKyUdGw6zQbmJsmOroioPsIlPsoIADcIKQBufn5QSFgERFweXmPs8dxpms4eGMbavYPwaFGANTgyyvxYHTE9FGZ3OShgAL0A0ScjY2yI6SSMLhhkknSUqmI7kBjBmtXCqhRwAh4mBc26kU%2031Kv3yUEJDkWvSg6y2UnCa0221W-yxkKenHx6hgmnZzM5u32FRKcCk0DYpUoRmAMhYlCg8ggwBuPNEkNJ7QAFCwAEYAKz6fzAJz6MAAlDaTl8ftqYFwXiZKJIoCbTcYiRdEko2DIpJIAHJwVAQPoAIgAIjIIPIWDG8EoMHBw5Ho1AYwAJOAAL1TSjgGr6AGYAAxpoRgKQsX1K2h9NThRLM7OxwxwBgyYCpqAe6QyY2lYCmFtQABsAA4oClaxEO5Qu7mAMKqyQICCD4eyMcT0N9ACMACYF0uRSlmvQPZJ3VuiRsqdALhrgEazX6CDH642-VoNIqxjW09iAA)

[Original Twitter Post](https://twitter.com/diegohaz/status/1309489079378219009)

Here's the relevant code:

```
type PathImpl<T, K extends keyof T> =
  K extends string
  ? T[K] extends Record<string, any>
    ? T[K] extends ArrayLike<any>
      ? K | `${K}.${PathImpl<T[K], Exclude<keyof T[K], keyof any[]>>}`
      : K | `${K}.${PathImpl<T[K], keyof T[K]>}`
    : K
  : never;

type Path<T> = PathImpl<T, keyof T> | keyof T;

type PathValue<T, P extends Path<T>> =
  P extends `${infer K}.${infer Rest}`
  ? K extends keyof T
    ? Rest extends Path<T[K]>
      ? PathValue<T[K], Rest>
      : never
    : never
  : P extends keyof T
    ? T[P]
    : never;

declare function get<T, P extends Path<T>>(obj: T, path: P): PathValue<T, P>;

const object = {
  firstName: "Diego",
  lastName: "Haz",
  age: 30,
  projects: [
    { name: "Reakit", contributors: 68 },
    { name: "Constate", contributors: 12 },
  ]
} as const;

get(object, "firstName"); // works
get(object, "projects.0"); // works
get(object, "projects.0.name"); // works

get(object, "role"); // type error
```

Comment: I'm a TS beginner, what those this line do 
```K | `${K}.${PathImpl<T[K], Exclude<keyof T[K], keyof any[]>>}```

Comment: This line is used to limit the available nested keys to non-Array prototype properties (e.g, `map`, `reduce`). See this playground with that rule omitted: https://shorturl.at/huBH1 and see how `map` is incorrectly allowed in the key now.

Comment: Very nice, however, the array access is broken in 4.5.2.

Comment: Tried using this in an Angular service and the typescript fails to compile with `error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.`

Comment: running in the playground fails with "[ERR]: get is not defined". which may be expected,  but I got disappointed because you advertised "...to see it in action" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only relevant keys (exlcuding the root ones), for example if you have a translation object, the you can use the following type:

```
type FlattenKeys<T> = T extends object
   ? {
        [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends infer U
           ? `${Extract<K, string>}${FlattenKeys<U> extends '' ? '' : '.'}${FlattenKeys<U>}`
           : never
     }[keyof T]
   : ''
```