# Typescript define type with function test

Tags: typescript, mongodb, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to create types that allow me to only search for specific things.

Lets assume I have this model and data:

```
interface UserModel {
    _id: string;
    username: string;
    party: UserPartyModel;
}

interface UserPartyModel {
    invites: number;
    rsvps: number;
}

//Test Data
{
    _id: '123',
    username: 'testuser',
    party: {
        invites: 18,
        rsvps: 3
    }
}
```

Using mongodb, I can query the root properties:

```
db.users.findOne({_id: '123'});
db.users.findOne({username: 'testuser'});
```

So I created this type to catch errors for things not in my model:

```
export declare type MongoManagerFilter<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

Mongodb also allows you to search inside an object such as this:

```
db.users.findOne({'party.invites': 18});
```

As you can see, now that I am using the previous type, `MongoManagerFilter`, I get an error that `'party.invites'` does not exist in `UserModel`.

So what I would like to do is run a function like so:

```
function isDotStringRegExp(obj: Object, dotKey: string): boolean {
    let keyData = dotKey.split('.');
    let objData = obj;

    for (let i = 0; i < keyData.length; i++) {
        let key = keyData[i];
        if (objData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            objData = objData[key];
        
            if (i === keyData.length - 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then add another type to do this:

```
export declare type MongoManagerDotStringFilter<T> = {
    [key: string]: (isDotStringRegExp(T, key) ? any : never);
};
```

Unfortunately, it won't let me run the `isDotStringRegExp` function in this type.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking on how to do this with Mongo, look at my other thread, specifically the playground code.

[Typescript Conditional Types Not Figuring Out Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368797/typescript-conditional-types-not-figuring-out-type)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a function with a type. So the function call `isDotStringRegExp(T, key)` is not possible since both `T` and `key` are types.

If you want type-safe access with dot-notation, take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68412497/10857778