# Typescript Conditional Types Not Figuring Out Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA2mILMdEAEXQQFcBbCcZAbwChlkB9YAEwH4AuZAZzCigA5gG5GyBFAhxIbAIJgeRGRDEBfevTABPAA4oACjIAWASQq7MAHgAqAGmQBpCNuQQAHpBBteyANYu6DDINgB8yAC84s6uHl4+fALC4hwhANoxALpuntQJAEq46FBsVvyCIEIOcCDaoeJMqQAGACS0MWoAdG1GYGYW1jYZLpkOAKLuCJhkbBBWAdpB6VkOC0vKkMgAPv6BwQDyAEYAVrhg27uLweXC4QBkiRVCoWpN9ACQTDut7S5dbRMpjM5mtgkMVpd1ioLqDkEdTngYXtHrdkA8bpVXg1kDwQBAAG7QcS4gnQMRaPSGEy2cIRSFgi69fqWWyrZFhck6fTIJkANTg0zm9h5OXiviZNNpHwMoryvh+oBg0Ccf26tEVysK-Cx71SMVl3l8sJsH0ayC15zicp51PBI3q711Nr6-MFtmG2lG5og-Ad7xJhKgppxyDxgY+PBlVsN9JCwdSQwMmWDPBq2nJHl0xXOsymcCkyC5KAAsoQhOhizU4EJoAAxYCYSBQGmROgfNIy0DO4w0zLcbuushChwGULqDPuLNQc553i+UuVCtVmtQDDYM4EEC2A0JNc4PCbkjkKjgcIMJgIQjlMh4YoACgAlHQNExxGRdGwVPs8XeYA2mzwC7lpWIDVnW-7QDST7nkwyAAPRwSEAASpgAMrIEQ+xjOhABy+w2MgADq+z5I42J-o20CdKwbCtgA5HRYiwcgFFNp0kjSLICitniADuGEqI+THIBoGj0AhyFoURJGOKh9A4OckD8KWsyYDxED8UBS6gSue4boQVh6QehBHpQ1BgKEQlaD6YAqRAmCdO+n6QN+EB3rQNE8HRSlgHRDgcSo8iKKGGkCZAj5qA+IhAA)

Assuming the given type:

```
export declare type MongoManagerFilter<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: (P extends keyof T ? T[P] : any);
};
```

When trying to specify the filter:

```
update.$setOnInsert.createdAt = new Date();
```

I get this error:

```
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type '"createdAt" extends keyof T ? T[keyof T & "createdAt"] : any'.ts(2322)
```

But if I change the filter to this it works:

```
export declare type MongoManagerFilter<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: any;
};
```

Why does the conditional statement not actually figure out the type?  It's just keeping the code as the type.

I know the filter doesn't make sense how it is, I have another type instead of `keyof T` to catch dot notation, but I am having the same issue with conditional statements not figuring out the actual type.

#### Full example

```js
interface CollectionDocument {
  _id?: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}

type PathImpl<T, Key extends keyof T> =
  Key extends string
  ? T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
    ? `${Key}.${PathImpl<T[Key], Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof Date | keyof Object | keyof string> & string>}`
      | `${Key}.${Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof Date | keyof Object | keyof string> & string}`
    : never
  : never;

type Path<T> = keyof T | PathImpl<T, keyof T>;

type PathValue<T, P extends Path<T>> =
    P extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
    ? Key extends keyof T
      ? Rest extends Path<T[Key]>
        ? PathValue<T[Key], Rest>
        : never
      : never
    : P extends keyof T
      ? T[P]
      : any;

export declare type MongoManagerFilter<T> = {
    [P in Path<T>]?: PathValue<T, P>;
};

export class MongoManagerCollection<T extends CollectionDocument> {
  constructor() {}
  
  updateOne(filter: MongoManagerFilter<T>) {
    // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    filter._id = '';
    filter.createdAt = new Date();
  }
}

// THIS WORKS
let testModel = new MongoManagerCollection<CollectionDocument>();
testModel.updateOne({_id: 'test', createdAt: new Date()});
```

EDIT
Adding another layer to this playground for more issues along same lines:

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA2mILMdEAEXQQFcBbCcZAbwChlkB9YAEwH4AuZAZzCigA5gG5GyBFAhxIbAIJhuyIjIhiAvvXqhIsRCgCqvaAFl0bCJmQQAHpBBteaLDjwFipStTB1xZY1AgcFQ8-IIgouIQFHDAmKECwmJMUFgQvDxG0ABKaWYWmBpaOtDwSMhZULk4+Za+TEKpZAAOGRUB1RAA4k3NtZgA2gC6RdrgpfrtOWk96C399ciNc83MQSF8iRHJyABuwBAA7m1hwsOjts3oUD4WCJhwUsgleuVmEegmcEFC0ABicV0AAVHsFVFAAPLNaAya68AA8QIAfL4AJBMAAkEAAjkogTtMUJFDx8eJCZA8QTkBjQHjrHZqI5kHIoFA4ABPeHfdkojjIIHIEnnMnUzDE-lUjFiiCUkUYkAykmSkC0kn0+xMllsznc3n8wX84VMTEgdDigW2DVOU4RZB895CT7fOC-KAA6VQEFsmK6KEwsBwxEogA+yGyECEAFEbM0MCAwmQ8NcDQ6nT9-oDoF6wb7oWyA1AEcjJbZgPxeEoAEboNLfEsxqBKbnDOVSX42OmWxnWrZCO1hiPR2OEBNJqDIUM2vs8BW7aCS9DNfAjzsMhw98J9vlTg2z+dy37oACS40LuDAFZ4DGNN+ph6oAnZPBI5Co4Cp6klh4A6sAwAALVVlE8N8wGVaRG2fEDvHAx4AGVmn-aBFWA18YLlGIbCIMswG+JAlBAShK33G8MTgbAmxAdkjWNLEcAoL4wAQf8lBfLx3zlXhgAALxQi01yZZshn7QiKGI8cZwgOcoAuGNrluXAHieF4yhQVMvnTN1M0hPNYULeEABUUWvWjvk4HgAAp1OdV13V0QyQ2QazNLs6A-XzQMjIAShok1riUKzCEdDSXQzD0HInJygrTUKtI9dy9IRbzfOpfzLOc2LXKgCLQwy2ztISgskqRHyRjlSA7CUEzb2pYxHmYhJNypUiHgiMhQqUKdmtohA4GMODqC4-A5yrGscDrEVSLYYBEEEfAEAG+M-2AEaeGrWsQA-SVDiQqROt7SKLIsgCyx4AyvOQABeFF1vGkAvMlBB0AoUD9s3SK2NA0YwHZaF+Rkf8jwoZpMEMgAaZAAGkIHZdVu2QABrGH0BgZAjKu8Rodhrt102TdxD5AyBix4ScaZcMnqgNh4SnCHdRFQniZh0mBKcCzQBgaBmVZUrkHoVFUT5AADDFaCx9QADpRZBACgZB+EtQh6N7jICx4SR9kUe5qAIY1rWVEgSK9dRoSjeR1GIUrAArc8zc11GpxRAAyPHhCRdQhb5gWmFDEWxZhyXReVzBVYgdXze13WI4NlBQ2N5BTbjiPLZtvA7a1x3kBdqcPa91EeD98WpdoGXAeB0GiZJpWbBVtX48r5mo-t5RVHTi3rdtpPm8z7Pe3doX+fRSLC4D4vg9D8Pm4b9khib-XW67rWU87xGI5712Ig9kVJOk8Qd-3egfr+0uIsu1ep8i0u5YrufUaMsRD9+lBS4ANXIsgw4MiH+Ktf6AIclEl1xA-3hn7DmXMi6i3AeOcM-At5MD5FjOGuN64MwHPwZBTIT7TyGEiSa-ZX7v0-kzGeENYFgDwTVM6JCWa-3ZiATm44tSlX5jePkhCQ5h0Vn-f8CtWRIhRKw40XBUR7igNvZAYi95owGAKF29cyr0EuPJZAdwlIoCPmpaKIV8rhXRmfBgqJZHPBADwhyQw8QAzfpw8G-JHJ5TCsCUEPo3K6SKoiKxRDbHInsdomyjjXH+k8kiDQD9lE3FUYpR4Gin5RQ+Do6ABh4wQDAFlU+aJjGgHPlrAyFiZxES5qGW60hNr0E-FocJCl7jROQJouJwV-FQBPAgNJ+iMkCiydgpEeTJEFJkmUsJckIlqJqXUhxUADDNDYKoVpgDFiYlAAgJQ4zmmzMlMYcU4y1mcRSRCEAJ4AibL8S5bSDlJRkGSUc+JjSkkbO2eUpRQyfDVN4E4cZGBsDnncIZTBTgPmuGXB4NC4BjLiCevGAQiYCwWQurQZAmhxAwFAGwCySKPQ8C2ac7y8y+ZMARUwFo0zIB7IgKi7SGLjmZSxUiCGhLVAUuuZpSZRKICzNhSKNFugJasDYFdZAAByflIhkAAHoRXIHQAjDl2kJaSGkLIBQfKFSHBbpAGFwqxUSqlTeOlkApYbNlVIVQ8gfBn2Vaq0lD1RXip2tjVk-kRS6ogPqlJfLaByuNQoSSKqY4ws-Na5AtrrD2sbOITQCLKkSAeK8+pMVXSVH+V8wgPyyZOEqP0FEqbY0JKgImtwyb0YmQ2ZGGIcR2ZsGYP4aAjVhAQ2iLEeIG8hDspvCdXgEsnUkosrQHlPB2CVoCOoCGtAMQbKvPWuIPAJ2YHUOoK1mqg3QFSKGvFZStCaoMgACSPHBZA34ITZEhnBegOAfCQH4AsM1Rxs2NLzYC+Ed73CfW8EidVh90hgH6B2qZqgu1wt7QK89YB+UQw9QqsA3qLUwvhcO0dKSrxgYgCayDvqvKzoeloU9yAq1QEvZI694yE0uCTSAN9OGv3FtLZgCy-KACMAAmAAzCBwDH6AACQgqOyuevyjD9BNUkB8KaXCgLakfvoOR8wlhv0sr-QAIlSDgdtywWjKd6GsYIEA5M8H5QZD9yBZgtH5UOugcGIN0AU2kNTKxeDaeQMMdDGqRWOnMBJgIX7O0Km7fyxT6QJYqdaBLUAuxyLsH5TpvT-BjOwbHRZ3z1nVN2Yc3OpzlxzxIeQJWOAbB13isxR6bMLidJBMLGJ-gbnTBScwDJ39XnaCWaU-53oCXVjrC01eGkIAeADF0-pwzzR+VDFnTF+DcWrNNZs0lobKXcs3pOfFNxcIytgH4+K78-5Ya9RoH+bDxhkAUCq3NqlC2SsVgq7hqrEskUOG7eIMiDhusih7ewHTDHmNDqe065D+GfWqD9eIIYZSMOSYKDV4ldX7tsG689qHAq3vRboF9r1P2oNoaGyN8ztAkfmfNahxzQA)

Seems I am getting this error as well due to the recursion in the types:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mpvBXw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Working on it now

Comment: It feels like a bug, though I don't really understand what you intend to do with this condition. If `P` is a key of `T`, then when would `P` not extend of a key from `T`? It feels like the condition will always be true and therefor equivalent to `[P in keyof T]?: T[P];`. Which would work just fine. I know you wrote "I know the filter doesn't make sense how it is", but it makes it hard to help you figure out the problem.

Comment: I will adjust this to add the dot notation

Answer (score 1):

Generic type `T` in:

```js
export class MongoManagerCollection<T extends CollectionDocument> {
  constructor() { }

  updateOne(filter: MongoManagerFilter<T>) {
    // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    filter._id = '';
    filter.createdAt = new Date();
  }
}
```

is a black box. `filter._id` is resolved as a non evaluated conditional type. Treat it as a non called function. Function which is has never been called does not return any value. Same is with `filter._id`.
`filter._id` coresponds to this:

```js
type PathValue<T, P extends Path<T>> =
  P extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
  ? Key extends keyof T
  ? Rest extends Path<T[Key]>
  ? PathValue<T[Key], Rest>
  : never
  : never
  : P extends keyof T ////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ? T[P]              // Property is resolved as a conditional type //
  : any;              ///////////////////////////////////////////////
```

As you might have noticed, `filter._id` is `P extends keyof T ? T[P] : any` instead of just `T[P]`.

There is a workaround. You can use `T[P & keyof T]` instead of `conditional type`.
See working example:

```js
interface CollectionDocument {
  _id?: string;
  createdAt: Date;
}

type PathImpl<T, Key extends keyof T> =
  Key extends string
  ? T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
  ? `${Key}.${PathImpl<T[Key], Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof Date | keyof Object | keyof string> & string>}`
  | `${Key}.${Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof Date | keyof Object | keyof string> & string}`
  : never
  : never;

type Path<T> = keyof T | PathImpl<T, keyof T>;

type PathValue<T, P extends Path<T>> =
  P extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
  ? Key extends keyof T
  ? Rest extends Path<T[Key]>
  ? PathValue<T[Key], Rest>
  : never
  : never
  : T[P & keyof T]

export declare type MongoManagerFilter<T> = {
  [P in Path<T>]?: PathValue<T, P>;
};

export class MongoManagerCollection<T extends CollectionDocument> {
  constructor() { }

  updateOne(filter: MongoManagerFilter<T>) {
    filter._id = ''; // ok
    filter.createdAt = new Date(); // ok
    filter.createdAt = 'sdf'; // expected error

  }
}

// THIS WORKS
let testModel = new MongoManagerCollection<CollectionDocument>();
testModel.updateOne({ _id: 'test', createdAt: new Date() });
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMVK6W)

If you are interested in `path` implementation, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69126879/typescript-deep-keyof-of-a-nested-object-with-related-type) answer, [this utility](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/274d8fb950f9944547921849fb6b3ee6e879e358/src/types/utils.ts#L86) and/or my [article](https://catchts.com/deep-pick).

I don't know MongoDB api and the requirements of your types so I can't say whether they need to be modified or not.

Also, you can get rid of generic :

```js
export class MongoManagerCollection {
  constructor() { }

  updateOne(filter: MongoManagerFilter<CollectionDocument>) {
    filter._id = ''; // ok
    filter.createdAt = new Date(); // ok

  }
}

// THIS WORKS
let testModel = new MongoManagerCollection();
testModel.updateOne({ _id: 'test', createdAt: new Date() });
```

but I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: I am going to add another playground for one step further.  My filter isn't working properly for update.  Added in all my mongo types.